# Approximating the Anderson Darling Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, numerical-methods

For various reasons, I need to work with the actual distribution of the Anderson Darling test statistic: in particular, I need its ln PDF. The only thing I've been able to find to get started is [Marsaglia's paper](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v009i02) which gives a series form for the CDF. This is theoretically workable, but it has a few problems. Chief among them is that I need the computation for potentially VERY large values of the statistic. The ln PDF as presented converges numerically pretty fast for small values of the statistic, but for large values, it's pretty much impossible to get something workable. I'm hoping that there's an alternate formulation that might work. I can work with the code pointed to for the middle part of the distribution, and I'm fairly confident that I can get a numerical approximation to work for small values, but I don't have a good way to calculate this for large values, especially since the small probability densities REALLY do matter for my application, since I'm log transforming them. I had done something similar for the Kolmogorov Smirnov distribution by using two alternative formulations of the Jacobi theta function for large and small values (calculating middle values out to more terms until both series essentially aggreed), but the integral in the Anderson Darling series is causing me fits.

Comment: Might have a look at David E A Giles, 'A saddlepoint approximation to the distribution
function of the Anderson-Darling test statistic,' (2001).

Comment: Is the expected distribution for your data uniform on $[0,1]$?  If not, what is it?

Comment: The expected distribution for my data is t distribution. That said, it’s a t distribution whose parameters are completely specified. I can compute the actual statistic relatively easily. What I need is to work with the probability distribution of the statistic itself